# WebSocket сервер и разные каналы

Tags: php

Приветствую! Уважаемые знатоки, возникла небольшая но важная проблемка в понимании и поднятии сервера на php. (Все это делаю на локалке).

**Задача для поднятия сервера:**

Есть страничка, на ней есть вкладочная навигация, все вкладки имеют свой адрес.
/tab1, /tab2/, tab3 и по аналогии дальше.
Мне нужно, чтобы при хождении по вкладкам у меня переключалось по каналам (где канал название вкладки, допустим **tab1**), и все кто на этом канале, каждому пользователю была уникальная отправка, а не всем сразу, то есть вкладку открыли, пользователя выбрали и пишем ему, то есть примерно как чат.

Ну вот вообще не понимаю, как организовать переключения по каналам и пользователям, что нужно сделать не могу въехать и как должен работать сервер я тоже не могу понять.

Кто - то может объяснить или показать, как должен выглядеть сервер с каналами?

Вот я начал писать скрипт:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();
ignore_user_abort(true);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);
socket_listen($socket);
while(true) {
   // Что тут нужно делать
}
socket_close($socket);
```

Или я не правильно делаю? Выручайте, очень хочу разобраться с этим, мне бы пинка под зад и пример как дальше плясать, я уже по начитался с многих источников и чаты поднимал, все работают, но у них не то что мне нужно, из чата переделать не вышло, немного недопонимаю как переделать.
Буду рад любой помощи.
Мне бы только понять как играться с сервером между каналами и пользователями и что для этого нужно, я не прошу писать тонны кода, только как нибудь операцию распределить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, все-же, пришлось читать и разбираться как все устроено.

Answer (score 1):

Советую вам начать с [Ratchet](https://packagist.org/packages/cboden/ratchet). Там довольно просто поднять websocket сервер с различными каналами.

Comment: Я не просил давать мне готовый вариант, спасибо конечно - но вы видимо плохо прочитали задачу. Мне нужно разобраться как это работает, а вы тулите готовый вариант, причем еще больше усложняя этим задачу, мне хочется самому разобраться как это работает, причем я конкретно сказал в чем мой затык, сейчас посидел поразбирался, и понял кое - что, но правильно понял или нет прошу подсказать, кто реально знает: 1). На 1 сокет вешается много соединений? 2). Сокетов может быть довольно много? 3). Я могу переключаться на сокеты используя массив для хождений по сокетам? С этими вопросами у меня трабла.